# Testing subdomain in development settings. foo.localhost:8000/

Tags: django, localhost, subdomain

How do you test subdomains when developing in django. I have to subdomain upp and running on test server but need to be able to test locally.

Simply put: How do i test foo.mysite.com/ using djangos test server?

Facebook integration forces me to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Use `hexxie.com`

You can test subdomains as well as facebook integration by using `hexxie.com` without changing hosts file. `hexxie.com` resolves to `localhost` i.e. `127.0.0.1`. You can also go to anything.hexxie.com and everything.hexxie.com, which will resolve to your local machine.See this [link](http://www.seanbehan.com/setup-wildcard-subdomain-on-localhost-for-development-work-without-etchosts-tomfoolery)

Answer (score 0):

For facebook integration you must need to change your local host address

So editing your `hosts` file in `/etc` like

> 127.0.0.1       localhost example.com